# jQuery selector - Match content of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way - any jQuery selector (i did found none on http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ), which can be used as exact match?

[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) is almost what i need, but not exactly.
":contains" searches in each element regex like this:

```
.*<query>.*
```

Which means, if i need to find link, which looks exactly like this:

```
<a href="#">Baxter</a>
```

And use this:

```
$("a:contains('Baxter')")
```

It matches also this, which i don't want to match:

```
<a href="#">I'm Peter Baxter, how are you?</a>
```

I know, that I can just take all elements and compare their content in the cycle, but I want to be sure, there's no easier way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, but it would be trivial to add as a plugin:

```
$.expr[':'].contentIs = function(el, idx, meta) {
    return $(el).text() === meta[3];
};
```

You can then use this as `$('a:contentIs("Baxter")')`

Comment: thats a really nice, little extension. I wonder why this isn't in core

Comment: @P.scheit It's quite expensive, computationally... Though, looking back, it could be improved with `$.text([el])` rather than `$(el).text()`.