# Select the tds containing a only the "specified text" and nothing else using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there any way that I can select the td containing only the specified text and nothing else?
 I have tried the following:

```
$("tr td:contains('1')")
```

but it returns the `td`s having 1 somewhere in text of a `td` as well. To be clear I was trying to get `<td>1</td>` from the html given below but it keeps returning all of these `td`s.

```
<tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>This contains 1 as well</td>
     <td><td>And this one contains 1 as well</td>
</tr>
```

Is there any way that I can force it to return only those `td`s that just contain `1` in their text and nothing else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector - Match content of elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673461/jquery-selector-match-content-of-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('td').filter(function (i, el) {
    return this.innerHTML == '1';
}).css('background-color','blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, filter, etc.

One easy way is to do:

```
$('td').each(function (i, el) {
    if (el.innerHTML === '1') {
        // DO SOMETHING
        console.log('It has only a 1 in it');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var selectors = $('tr td').map(function () {
    if (this.innerHTML == '1') {
        return $(this);
    }
});
//result: selectors is the td elements with text "1".
```